# modulo algorithm for prime numbers

Tags: java, primes, modulo

I'm trying to get a program to get me the prime numbers from a certain range (user inputs the maximum number) and this variable called `maxNumber` will be used to stop the while loop. The control variable used starts at the first prime number 2 and is called `i` and will be used to print out the prime numbers (when found) and natural numbers, respectively.

My problem is that I'm not really sure if my algorithm inside the main method and mutator method are both correct and I have a problem where I am putting the user input (the max number) but nothing is happening at all after that -- basically, it is compiling and running but not responding when inputting the first variable.

Help would very much be appreciated !

```
import java.util.*;
public class PrimeCalculator {

    private static int maxNumber;
    private static int divisibleCount;

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 2;

    System.out.println("Enter the maximum amount of numbers you want to find prime numbers within: ");
    maxNumber = scanner.nextInt();

    while(i <= maxNumber)
        isPrime(i);
            if(divisibleCount < 2)
        System.out.println(i + " is a prime number");
            if(divisibleCount > 2)
        System.out.println(i + " is not a prime number.");
            divisibleCount = 0;
            i++;
    }

public static void isPrime(int n) {
    divisibleCount = 0;
    for(int x = 1; x <= maxNumber; x++ )
         if(n%x == 0)
             divisibleCount++;
             }

}
```

Comment: If you want to do object-oriented programming, try to rfrain as much as possible from static methods and variables. Also, why do you run your loop to maxNumber and not to n?

Comment: Why you keep running `for` loop if you already know it's not prime? Why you have nested loops?

Answer (score 1):

Although I do not think it is clear what you're asking, I will make a few suggestions.

1. First of all, at your main method, change `if(divisibleCount < 2)` to `if(divisibleCount <= 2)` because **primes are divided by 1 and themselves** (so, "divisibleCount" is 2).
2. Also, in your while loop, you should check if `i` equals one and say that it is not a prime.
3. As said in the comments, at the isPrime method , you can change the loop to <strike>`for(int x = 1; x <=`***`n`***`; x++ )` as it is impossible for a number to be perfectly divided by soomething greater (i.e. 6 divided by 10 cannot have modulo 0)</strike>

   **EDIT**: As dcsohl suggested, it is even better to have `for(int x = 1; x <= Math.sqrt(n); x++)` *(see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838547/modulo-algorithm-for-prime-numbers/20840841?noredirect=1#comment31299845_20840841))*
4. Check your syntax. At the while loop, you do not **open and close brackets**, so only `isPrime(i)` gets executed in the loop. Imagine

   ```
   while(i <= maxNumber){
       isPrime(i);
   }
   if(divisibleCount < 2) // ....etc
   ```

   And since i is *never incremented* in the loop, it it always 2, so ... we have got an **infinite loop**!
5. *(General improvement)* Surround the `maxNumber = scanner.nextInt();` in a [try-catch](/questions/tagged/try-catch) block to avoid crashing when entering say, a string instead of an int.

These are the problems I found, hope I helped you.

---

PS. If you have any other question like this (i.e. *general code checking*), you should ask them at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than Stack Overflow

Comment: +1 for finding the missing brackets. As another general improvement: Let `isPrime` actually return a `boolean` instead of using that static variable.

Comment: To go further on point 3, you can actually change the `isPrime()` loop to `for(int x = 1; x <= Math.sqrt(n); x++)`... you only need to check for factors less than or equal to the square root, since the result of `n/x` (where `x <= sqrt(n)`) will be some value y that is greater than `sqrt(n)`. Therefore, when you have checked every possible factor less than `sqrt(n)` you have also checked every actual factor greater than `sqrt(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

I won't answer your Java questions, but the normal algorithm for enumerating the prime numbers is the Sieve of Eratosthenes, invented by a Greek mathematician over two thousand years ago:

```
function primes(n)
    sieve := makeArray(2..n, True)
    for p from 2 to n
        if sieve[p]
            output p # prime
            for i from p*p to n step p
                sieve[i] := False
```

This algorithm examines every number *p* from 2 to *n*; if *p* is prime, the loop on *i* marks *False* all the multiples of *p*; the *i* loop starts from the square of *p* because all smaller multiples will already have been marked *False* by smaller primes.

If you're interested in programming with prime numbers, I modestly recommend [this essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) at my blog.

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.io.*;
class Prime
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        long i,j,n=1000000100000L;
        long sum=0;
        long i1=1000000000000L;
        long c;
        System.out.println("The Prime Numbers are:");
        for(i=i1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            c=0;
            for(j=2;j<=10000000;j++)
            {
                if(i%j==0)
                    c=c+1;
                if(c==1)
                    break;
            }
            if(c==0)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
                sum=sum+i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The Sum of Prime numbers are:"+sum);
    }
}
```